# multiple invocations of OptionParser.parse_args() within the same python execution

Tags: python, optionparser

I have the following example setup:

```
|-- main_script.py
`-- module
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- submodule.py
```

where the contents of main_script are:

```
import optparse
import module

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
group = optparse.OptionGroup("submodules options")
group.add_option("","--main_script.bar", dest="bar", action="store_true")
parser.add_option_group(group)

opts,args = parser.parse_args()

if opts.bar:
    print ("Bar")
```

and the contents of submodule.py are:

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
group = optparse.OptionGroup(parser, "submodules options")
group.add_option("","--module.submodule.foo", dest="foo", action="store_true")
parser.add_option_group(group)

opts,args = parser.parse_args()

if opts.foo:
    print ("Foo")
```

Since main_script imports submodule the parse_args  from submodule is the called. Is there anyway to combine these instances of OptionParser and raise an error if there are option conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to break your logic into functions.  You should not execute logic at the global module scope in the first place, but use a `if name == "__main__"` wrapper construct.

You could define a function `add_options(parser)` to each module that must define options, and call this at the root level before calling `parse_args`:

```
import optparse
import submodule

def add_options(parser):
    parser.add_option(...)

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    add_options(parser)
    submodule.add_options(parser)
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    #...

if __main__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The above method would work if I had complete control over the clients of 'module' & 'submodule'. I've used a global approach to demonstrate the example, but thats not exactly the case in my actual code.

What I'm trying to achieve is to expose 'command line options' via various modules in my library. This is so that any client of the library that exposes a command line interface has access to the command line options exposed by any submodule that it includes, to enable options such as 'debug mode', 'profiling' etc..

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to solve this problem from the outside in - I have an initial implementation that  patches the optparse module by replacing the OptionParser class with a subclass of OptionParser and overloads the parse_args method + exposes a new delayed_parse_args method. I'm sharing snippets from this solution in case anyone else finds its useful or can make an improvement to it.

**optparse_patch.py**

```
import optparse

def patch_opt_parser():
    optparse.stashed_parsers = {}

    class OptionParserEx(optparse.OptionParser):
        def delayed_parse_args(self, callback):
            optparse.stashed_parsers[self] = callback

        def parse_args(self, args=None, values=None):
            for parser, callback in getattr(optparse,"stashed_parsers").items():
                # add all the option_list & option_groups from the individual
                # parsers in stashed_parsers to `self`
            for parser, callback in getattr(optparse,"stashed_parsers").items():
                # update `parser` to inherit the option_lists and option_groups from 
                # self. then ....
                _o, _a = optparse._OptionParser.parse_args( parser, args, values )
                callback( _o, _a t)
            return getattr(optparse,"_OptionParser").parse_args(self, args, values)

    optparse._OptionParser = optparse.OptionParser
    optparse.OptionParser = OptionParserEx

patch_opt_parser()
```

This allows submodules to 'stash' their expected options and have the command line options evaluated at a later stage when the client of the module actually provides an OptionParser and calls the parse_args method on it's own OptionParser. An example of such a use case is as follows:

**module.py**

```
import optparse_patch
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
group = optparse.OptionGroup(parser, "module options")
group.add_option("-f", dest="flip", action="store_true")
parser.add_option_group(group)
def cli_callback ( opts, args ):
    if opts.flip: 
        print "flip"
opts, args = parser.delayed_parse_args ( cli_callback )
```

**main.py**

```
import module
import optparse


myparser = optparse.OptionParser()
mygroup = optparse.OptionGroup(myparser, "main options")
mygroup.add_option("-j", dest="jump", action="store_true")
myparser.add_option_group(mygroup)
opts, args = myparser.parse_args()
if opts.jump:
     print "jump"
```

calling the program main.py results in the following outputs:

*python main.py --help*

```
Usage: main.py [options]

Options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

  module options:
    -f        

  main options:
    -j
```

*python main.py -j -f*

```
flip
jump
```